# ReactJS: Local images not loading (Using path from overrides)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I set up a `config-overrides.js` and I have an assets folder that contains my images folder. When I try to call an image, it does not show up.

I tried using `require()` but it doesn't work.

Here is my config-overrides.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    const aliasses = {
        Main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/'),
        Component: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
        Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
        Layouts: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/layouts'),
        Routes: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/routes'),
    };

    config.resolve.alias = {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        ...aliasses
    };


    return config;
  }
```

My image

```
<img src="Assets/images/image.png" alt=""  />
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the package.json of my project:

```
    {
  "name": "secrethaha",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.19.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ajv": "6.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.3"
  }
}
```

My latest addition is the react-app-rewired.

Comment: try to append / at the end of the relative path i.e Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/'),

Comment: @VishalRajole I tried to append / but it's not working as well

Comment: post your package.json

Comment: @DanielLizik updated my question

Comment: @DanielaEchavez try using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader

Comment: @DanielaEchavezs and thanks for posting your package.json. with that, other people will know what tools you are able to use in your setup.

Comment: @DanielaEchavez CRA already configured with `url-loader` you should be able to `import` the images directly as i showed in my answer, Have you tried it ?

Comment: @AsafAviv it worked! Thanks :D

Comment: @DanielaEchavez You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [`url-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) configured you can `import` the image directly, or if you use CRA `url-loader` is already configured out of the box

```
import MyImg from './Assets/images/image.png';

<img src={MyImg} alt="My image" />
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: depends on OP's webpack/babel setup

Comment: @DanielLizik You're right, my bad to assume it's already configured.